# Angular 2 - List of built-in pipes and their parameters?

Tags: angular

I'm currently learning the awesome Angular 2 framework and came across some cool pipes and transformations using pipe parameters. For example:

```
<td>{{product.price| currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</td>
```

Could you guys let me know if there's a list of built-in pipes available anywhere on the internet? It would be cool to look through all the stuff I can do, listed with description.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could have a look on the angular.io website in the "api preview" section: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/.

Just enter "pipe" in the search area and you will have all the available pipes under the "angular2/common" package.

Comment: Heads up, this won't show Angular 2 pipes anymore. It goes to the latest stable version (currently 4). So don't be surprised if your TitleCase pipe doesn't work for you. The link in [Sunny's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36490416/2908576) shows which pipes are in Angular 2 specifically.

Comment: There is option to select v2 on the left. You can directly go via this link:

https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I kept searching and found this wonderful article which gave me a lot of information, including pipes with angular 1 and angular 2 support.

Maybe this will be helpful for other people who had my concern too..

https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/03/angular2-series-working-with-pipes/